# Алгоритм нахождения суммы элементов

Tags: c++

Имеется функция:

```
int recform(int p){
    if(p==0) return A[0];
    int s=0,i;
    for( i=0; i<m+1; i++) s += pow(p,i)*d[i];
    for( i=1; i<=k; i++) s += c[i]*A[p-i];

    return s;
}
```

Функция считает элементы последовательности: `A[n] = A[n-1]+d[0]+d[1]*n+d[2]*n^n;`(это частный случай).

`A[0] = 1, p = n, m=2, k=1, d[2]={1,2,1}, c[i]` всегда равен `1`, можно пропустить.

Сам вопрос: если `p = 10`, то суммирование при первом цикле работает странно.

В данном случае `0+1 = 1; 1+20 = 21;` а вот уже на третьем элементе 21+100 = 120 хотя должно 121. При вычислении других элементов работает нормально.

Если надо вся программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int k, m, *c, *d, *A, *temp;

int recform(int p){
    if(p==0) return A[0];
    int s=0,i;
    for( i=0; i<m+1; i++) s = s + pow(p,i)*d[i];
    for( i=1; i<=k; i++) s = s + c[i]*A[p-i];

    return s;
}

main(){
    int i;
    cin>>k>>m;

    c = new int[k+1];
    for(i=1; i<=k; i++) cin>>c[i];

    d = new int[m+1];
    for(i=0; i<m+1; i++) cin>>d[i];

    temp = new int[k];
    for(i=0; i<k; i++) cin>>temp[i];

    int p,q;
    cin>>p>>q;

    A = new int[p+1];
    for(i=0; i<k; i++) A[i] = temp[i];
    for(i=k; i<=p; i++) A[i] = recform(i);

    cout<<A[p] % q;

}
```

Входные данные:

```
1 2

1

1 2 1

1

10 100
```

Вывести должен: 6

Comment: Неплохо бы проверять чтобы p было >= k и q != 0. И непонятно почему p передается как аргумент, а остальные значения как глобальные переменные. P.S. если делаете вид что пишите на с++ (а по тегу это так), то используйте vector<int> вместо new, а лучше vector<double>, так как у вас используется возведение в степень для вещественных чисел. Или удаляйте выделенную память через delete[].

Answer (score 1):

Что такое `pow`? Если это возведение в степень - то вы, на самом деле, считаете

```
A[n] = c[1]*A[n-1] + d[0] + d[1]*n + d[2]*n^2
```

при k=1 и m=2.

Answer (score 1):

Не следует возводить в целочисленную степень через pow(), если нет уверенности, что pow() перегружена для целых степеней. Просто, умножайте в цикле аккумулирующее произведение на основание степени.